# Move cursor to beginning of visible text in current buffer

Tags: motion

Is there a shortcut key combination for moving the cursor to the beginning, resp. end, of the *visible* text in the current buffer, i.e. to the first, resp. last, cursor position that can be seen on the current screen, without scrolling up or down? Contrast this with the *absolute* beginning/end of the text in the current buffer, for which the shortcuts `M-<`, resp. `M->`, will work.

Comment: @phils: I've added a clarification.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ah, you're looking to move point to the top or bottom of the *window*.

<kbd>M-r</kbd> calls `move-to-window-line-top-bottom` which cycles through the top/middle/bottom positions.  You can also use a prefix argument, for which "zero means top of window, negative means relative to bottom of window."

e.g.:

- <kbd>M-0</kbd><kbd>M-r</kbd>
- <kbd>M--</kbd><kbd>M-r</kbd>

Or write a command to call `move-to-window-line` directly with an appropriate argument.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the following bindings to easily get to the top (t) and bottom (b):

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-S-t") (lambda () (interactive)
                (push-mark (point)) ; save place
                                (let ((current-prefix-arg 0))
                  (call-interactively 'move-to-window-line-top-bottom))))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-S-b") (lambda () (interactive)
                (push-mark (point)) ; save place
                (let ((current-prefix-arg '(-1)))
                  (call-interactively 'move-to-window-line-top-bottom))))
```

They are specific calls to `move-to-window-line-top-bottom` (with needed prefix args) to go to those spots directly, instead of pressing `M-r` two or three times.

You may wish to use different bindings, but the recipe of going there directly is there.

Comment: You might want to rethink this code, hard.  `call-interactively` isn't just unnecessary here because you can just call (almost all) interactive functions directly (like `(move-to-window-line-top-bottom -1)`), you could even save some indirection and call `(move-to-window-line -1)`, the function `move-to-window-line-top-bottom` actually calls.